# Can this data generate this graph?

Tags: r, self-study

This is the desired graph

[image]

Here is the data: https://github.com/UnlimitedR/share/blob/main/mydata.csv

If so, could anyone please tell me how should I implement the R codes for it? Including drawing the CI area.

This is currently my code

```
df <- read.csv("mydata.csv")
print(sum(df$PRS))

library(ggplot2)
df$incidence <- 100 * df$PRS / sum(df$PRS,na.rm=T)
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = CIT, y = incidence)) +
  geom_line()
print(g)
```

But the result is

[image]

btw, what does the incidence of PRS means? I think PRS is a binary variable?

I dont know if I have understood the meaning of incidence of PRS correctly?

---

Thanks for the help from Dave, I rewrote the code with ggplot

```
dat <- rio::import("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UnlimitedR/share/main/mydata.csv")
library(ggplot2)
library(ggeffects)

mod <- glm(PRS ~ CIT, data=dat, family=binomial)
g <- ggpredict(mod, terms="CIT [all]") 

ggplot(g, aes(x, y = predicted, color="yellow")) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), alpha = 0.5) +
  ggtitle("") +
  labs(x = "CIT", y = "Incidence of PRS, %") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = ~sprintf("%.0f", .x*100)) +
  #scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.2,0.9))+
  scale_color_discrete(name="",
                       labels="95% CI")
```

However, the color seems to have a little bit problems.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're plotting the raw data, whereas the authors of the graphic you want to emulate are plotting a model fit. Do you know what kind of model they might be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```r
dat <- rio::import("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UnlimitedR/share/main/mydata.csv")
library(ggplot2)
library(ggeffects)

mod <- glm(PRS ~ CIT, data=dat, family=binomial)
g <- ggpredict(mod, terms="CIT [all]") 
plot(g) + 
  ggtitle("") + 
  labs(x="CIT", y="Incidence of PRS")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The code above assumes that the underlying model predicting `PRS` with `CIT` is a logistic regression.

To print without the `%` symbol, using the code in the comments:

```r
plot(g) + 
  ggtitle("") + 
  labs(x="CIT", y="Incidence of PRS, %") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = ~sprintf("%.0f", .x*100)) + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA))
#> Scale for y is already present.
#> Adding another scale for y, which will replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

---

##### Edit: Modifying code in question

```r
ggplot(g, aes(x, y = predicted)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour="Predictions\nw/95% CI")) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high, fill="Predictions\nw/95% CI"), alpha = 0.5, colour="transparent") +
  ggtitle("") +
  labs(x = "CIT", y = "Incidence of PRS, %") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = ~sprintf("%.0f", .x*100)) +
  #scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.15,0.9)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values="gray50") + 
  scale_colour_manual(values="black") + 
  labs(colour="", fill = "")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Im sorry Im new to R. I still have some minor problems about ploting. I checked it in RStudio and found that the `g` object is like a dataframe with three columns `CIT`, `Predicted` and `95% CI`. Does that mean the `plot` function can automatically detect the predicted value and CI area and draw it? (like take the second column to draw the line and third column to draw the band?)

Comment: The first class for `g` is `ggeffects`, which means when you use `plot()` on the object `g`, it will first try to find `plot.ggeffects()` which is defined in the `ggeffects` package.  That does know to use the predicted values and the confidence intervals to make the line and confidence envelope.  To see the code for the function, you could type: `ggeffects:::plot.ggeffects` into R and press enter (without the parentheses after the function).

Comment: Thank you! one last minor request is that, I want to make the graph as close as to the example. So I modified the plot statement a little bit
```
plot(g) + 
  ggtitle("") + 
  labs(x="CIT", y="Incidence of PRS, %") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA))
```
But it still shows the percentage symbol, how should I modify it to not show it?

Comment: @user900476 I updated the answer to remove the percent sign.

Comment: Hello, I rewrote the code with ggplot and tried to add a legend like in the example, would you mind taking a look at it?

Comment: @user900476 I would probably modify a couple of things - I edited my answer to include what I would do.  The colour attribute of a ribbon is actually not the fill colour (that's the fill attribute), but the border around the filled in region.